# Flutter, how can I add new document in Firestore based on a value in a different document?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-web

so I have two collections in my `Firestore`, `items` and `notifications`. In `items` I have a `field` with a date, say 1 week ahead. What I am trying to figure out is how can I make my app to automatically add a new document in my collection `notifications` when the date in my `items` collection is equal to todays date. Is this possible?

Comment: You should consider using cloud functions for that

Comment: The "automatically" part here is not clear to me. You will have to write code for this. If you want to do this in your Flutter app, you'll [start with a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) that you either [get](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) periodically or that you [listen](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) to continuously. Outside of your app, you should look at something like Cloud Functions or Cloud Run as Vinamra commented, but you'd still be writing similar/a subset of the code there.

Comment: Hi, with automatically I ment without me pressing any button or do something to start that function. I want it to check when the app reload or opens at first time.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen , if I want to do this in my app, where should I put the query? What page do I put it in? If I want it to listen everytime the app is running or starts.

Comment: If you want to run some code each time your app starts, you can put it in your `main` function.